# How multiple developers can work on the same android app connected to a single Firebase console?

Tags: android, firebase

My local android app is synced up in google firebase console with my SHA key configured in google.services.json. How do the developer on other end
can setup the project to use the same firebase console and json file.
We are trying phone based authentication. While setup at my end works is fine, but the developer on the other end is getting this error - This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console.
Please help me with the correct way to do this.

Comment: add that other developer's SHA key on firebase console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

So for other developers, generate the SHA-1 Key as described in the picture

[image: Generating SHA-1 key]

Go to Firebase Console:

- Settings
- Your Apps
- Add Fingerprint and paste the SHA.

A solution for the comment:
So the answer is well written in the error. You can't have two projects of the same package name. Even if you delete it. It will take a least 4-5 days to get deleted fully from the developer's console.

So the only solution is to generate a new SHA-1 key by custom signing the app by generating a signed apk from the android studio. Or just create a new project with different package name both ways will work for now.

Hope this info helps. Do let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: When I try to add the other SHA-Key, it throws me this error - An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project. You can omit the SHA-1 for now and read more about this situation and how to resolve it. Any suggestion here?

Comment: How do I keep the package name different for the project when both of us are working on the same app? Our SHA-Key is different but the package name is the same. please advise.

Comment: @pal Have you tried adding the fingerprint, from the console?

Comment: I have first added SHA key from my app in the console. Once that is successful, I am now trying to add another developer's SHA key into the firebase.console - > add fingerprint

Comment: I suggest you to generate a signed APK that will give you a new SHA-1 https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signing-manually

Comment: Finally it worked. Thank you so much. This time changed the project name and added the 2 SHA keys in the firebase console.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Sharan's answer, that is the correct one, you can add those SHA1 keys in your Firebase console going to

> Project configuration - ADD FINGERPRINT

[image]

Remember to select the correct project at the `Android apps` panel in order to add those keys

Comment: Yes, I wanted this screenshot with the blurred one. Thanks Gaston